# Why execute with param method does not work?

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I am creating a master-details page in adf.

The master is iterator for department and the details is iterator for employees .. until now it is ok

I added execute with params method(with bind parameter "BEmpid")
to look for a specific employee in the details but it doesn't filter the result

Can you please help me?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
  <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl1">
    <af:panelTabbed position="above" id="pt1" partialTriggers="i1:b1">
      <af:iterator id="i1" var="dept" value="#{bindings.DepartmentVO2.collectionModel}">
      <af:showDetailItem id="tab1" text= "#{dept.DepartmentName}">
        <af:inputText label="dept id" id="it1"  value="#{dept.DepartmentId}" disabled="true"/>
        <af:inputText label="dept name" id="it2"  value="#{dept.DepartmentName}" disabled="true"/>
        <af:inputText label="location id" id="it3"  value="#{dept.LocationId}" disabled="true"/>
        <af:inputText label="manager id" id="it4"  value="#{dept.ManagerId}" disabled="true"/>
         <af:panelFormLayout id="pfl1">
            <af:inputText value="#{bindings.BEmpId.inputValue}" label="#{bindings.BEmpId.hints.label}"
                          required="#{bindings.BEmpId.hints.mandatory}" columns="#{bindings.BEmpId.hints.displayWidth}"
                          maximumLength="#{bindings.BEmpId.hints.precision}"
                          shortDesc="#{bindings.BEmpId.hints.tooltip}" id="it9">
              <f:validator binding="#{bindings.BEmpId.validator}"/>
              <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" pattern="#{bindings.BEmpId.format}"/>
            </af:inputText>
            <af:commandButton actionListener="#{bindings.ExecuteWithParams.execute}" text="ExecuteWithParams"
                       disabled="#{!bindings.ExecuteWithParams.enabled}" id="b1"/>
          </af:panelFormLayout>
          
           <af:panelTabbed position="above" id="pt2" partialTriggers="b1">
            <af:iterator id="i2" var="employees" value="#{dept.EmployeesVO}">
                <af:showDetailItem id="tab2" text="#{employees.FirstName}">
                    <af:inputText label="employee id" id="it5"  value="#{employees.EmployeeId}" disabled="true"/>
                    <af:inputText label="first name" id="it6"  value="#{employees.FirstName}" disabled="true"/>
                    <af:inputText label="last name" id="it7"  value="#{employees.LastName}" disabled="true"/>
                    <af:inputText label="department id" id="it8"  value="#{employees.DepartmentId}" disabled="true"/>
                </af:showDetailItem>
            </af:iterator>
          </af:panelTabbed>
       
        </af:showDetailItem>
      </af:iterator>
    </af:panelTabbed>
  </af:panelGroupLayout>
 
</ui:composition>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Reason For Not Working :-

Here is the code to retrieve the Employees data,

"
<af:iterator id="i2" var="employees" value="#{dept.EmployeesVO}"> ",

In the case Tree/TreeTable binding, ADF At run time , in order to retrieve the Employees data, it will dynamically create view instance (some thing like 'EmployeesVO11') and use that e to retrieve the data i.e in another words , the ADF UI will not use the 'EmployeesVO' view instance under 'DepartmentVO' instance  added to your AM.

Where as 'ExecuteWithParams' action binding must have binded to AM's DepartmentVO.EmployeesVO instance.

### Work Around

one work around to achieve your use case .
For your 'EmployeeVO, add 'where' a clause like ' EMP_ID = :pEmpId or :pEmpId IS NULL' and define a where clause param called 'pEmpId' and default it using groovy "adf.context.current.sessionScope.get('sEmpId')", and then populate session scope variable called 'sEmpId' from UI .